# Which cable do I need?

Tags: array, scsi, hp-proliant

I just bought an HP MSA30 hard drive array. I believe it's the dual bus model because the interface card looks like this....

[image]

Can anyone tell me what type of cable I need to connect this to my server? I have an HP Proliant DL380 and it has an integrated SCSI interface on the mobo that looks like this....

[image]

I believe I need a 30-pin VHDCI to VHDCI cable to get things working properly...is that correct?

[image]

Comment: Looks like ultra-scsi to me. Was there no manual with this?

Comment: Look at the website where you bought it, it should say.

Comment: Well, I bought it from an online Ebay store. The only thing they mention about a cable is that they do not include one...but you can buy it for an additional sum of money. What is confusing me is that I've been reading online, and it seems like the cable I need is being called different things. So I've heard that I need SCSI, 30-pin VHDCI, 30-pin SCSI...I'm assuming these are all the same cable.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [HP Website](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/archives_North_America/11738_na_v16/11738_na.HTML), the HDD array is VHDCI. The server looks like HD68 to me. So you would need VHDCI to HD68, like [this](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/521080-REG/Avid_7070_03158_01_VHDCI_Male_to_HD68.html).